# Google chrome disable autoupdate

Tags: google-chrome, google, auto-update

How to disable autoupdate on Mac OS X without removing any files or changing permissions?

Comment: [see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23142998) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18483087)

Comment: ./ksinstall --help [-KeystoneInstallTool usage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/207998/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has [shared](https://support.google.com/installer/answer/147176?hl=en) knowledge how to disable it correctly. You don't need to remove or mangle any files you have on your system.

You should set check interval to zero like this:

`defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0`

After you done you can update google products from command line or Finder by running `CheckForUpdatesNow.command` command which can be found in one of following locations:

- /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/
- ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/

Comment: @JashJacob 2 days delay. I can't break rules

Comment: I have checkInterval set to 0, but when I go to "Chrome -> About Google Chrome" to see my version it will automatically install updates, without asking me first. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Nope, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

The "official" Google-given method given is this, but it doesn't always work. The updater sometimes, on some systems, finds a way to reset itself and update anyway.

In Terminal:

```
defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0
```

The most foolproof method is to deny Chrome the permissions it needs to install the update software and run it. Empty these directories:

```
/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/
~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/
```

Then change the permissions on both folders named GoogleSoftwareUpdate so that there's no owner and no read/write/execute permissions.

In terminal:

```
cd /Library/Google/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate
sudo chmod 000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate
cd ~/Library/Google/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate
sudo chmod 000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate
```

If you want to be double-certain, then do the same for the folder Google one level up.

```
cd /Library/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup Google
sudo chmod 000 Google
cd ~/Library/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup Google
sudo chmod 000 Google
```

I did this immediately after installing the Chrome version I need for my machine, and it worked perfectly. Now when I check About Google Chrome it gives me the error "Update failed (error: 10)" It's still trying to update, but it can't do it any more.