# Disable auto-update of Google Chrome with Firewall?

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, java

I need to keep using an older version of Chrome to access an old work VPN which requires Java applets and for some reason crashes after several minutes when launched from Safari. The latest versions of Chrome has Java applets disabled, so I need to download an old version of Chrome and disable the autoupdate. I know you can disable the updater interval, but can I disable it by blocking certain domains in `/etc/hosts` by pointing them to 127.0.0.1 or using Little Snitch to block connections?

Comment: [see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23142998) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18483087)

Comment: ./ksinstall --help [-KeystoneInstallTool usage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/207998/)

Answer (score 2):

From this [link](http://osxdaily.com/2012/04/06/disable-google-chrome-automatic-software-update/):

This works to stop Google Chrome from updating itself automatically in Mac OS X:

- Launch the Terminal, found in /Applications/Utilities/
- Enter the following defaults write command and hit return:

`defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0`

- Exit out of Terminal and restart Google Chrome

Direct [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=disable%20chrome%20updates%20os%20x) here.

YMMV.

Comment: Thanks! If I accidentally open the "About Chrome" box - will that still trigger the auto update? (I've read on the forums that this was the case at some point).

Comment: No idea, @NicCottrell, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This method did not use a firewall, but is easy as possible.

1. Open the **Application** folder in the finder
2. Right-click on the **Google Chrome** app
3. Select **Show Packaged Content** and open the **Contents** folder
4. Open **info.plist** file with your favourite text editor
5. Search for **KSUpdateURL** and rename the string value URL to something else (127.0.0.1)