# How do I stop ksfetch

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, big-sur

I frequently see the ksfetch and nrlsession running on my activity monitor. Any idea of how I can stop this process?

Comment: See this related post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/207998/119271. One of the answers has instructions on how to disable the ksfetch process.

Comment: See this [question/answer post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/205249/119271) on `nrlsession`

Comment: I have done all this. How do I know it's working

Comment: My Mac is saying zsh no such file directory

Comment: Without knowing what you did, it's impossible to address your questions.

Comment: ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/ksinstall I typed this